# Можно ли вставить кодом содержимое шаблона wpbackery page builder?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня есть на главной странице сайта блок с List Items, который я добавил в редактировании страницы при помощи wpbackery page builder и после я данный блок добавил в Мои шаблоны. Могу ли я вывести этот шаблон **кодом** на другой странице? [Шаблон](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJkTG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В WP Bakery такие вещи выводятся шорткодами. Например

```
[recentposts layout="grid" columns="1" post_author='.$id_author.' cat_slug='.$cat_user.' number_posts="10" orderby="date" order="DESC" excerpt_count="0" show_readmore="no" show_author="yes" show_thumb="no" pagination="yes"]
```

В данном примере выведены последние посты модуля Recent Post по автору категории и т.д. Данный шорт код кастомизирован и врядли будет работать у вас. По умолчанию это бы выглядело так:

```
[recentposts layout="grid" columns="1" cat_slug='all' number_posts="10" orderby="date" order="DESC" excerpt_count="0" show_readmore="no" show_author="yes" show_thumb="no" pagination="yes"]
```

Где настройки шорткода это настройки как вы указываете в админке данного виджета:

```
cat_slug - слаг категории
show_readmore - показать кнопку читать далее или нет
show_thumb - показать тамбнейл поста или нет
pagination - включать пагинацию или нет и т.д
```

Чтобы таким образом вывести свой шаблон, нужно для этого шаблона создать шорткод там же в настройках шорткодов в админке.

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду пробовать